# How to get bash variables work on awk pipe

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I can't get variable from my bash script to work on awk piping.

```
SERVER_PORT="27018"
...
HOLDER=`netstat -tlpn | awk -v sp=$SERVER_PORT '/:sp */ {split($NF,a,"/"); print a[1]}'`
```

After executing command for this variable next equation is TRUE!

```
...
if [ "$HOLDER" == "" ]; then
...
```

If I run

```
netstat -tlpn | awk '/:27018 */ {split($NF,a,"/"); print a[1]}'
```

on my shell window everything is fine and it gives me the PID of the process.

So my question is: how to pass variable to awk correctly or something has broken?
Running CentOS 7

Answer (score 8):

Inside a regular expression constant awk doesn't expand variables. So `/:sp */` is literally `/:sp */`.

You need to make that match a string: `$0 ~ ":"sp" *"`

awk scripts are made up of `pattern {action}` pairs. `/:27018 */` is a pattern (using a regexp constant). As I said at the beginning awk doesn't expand variables *inside* a regexp constant so `/:sp */` is matching those literal characters.

There are other patterns possible beyond a regexp constant. Even static strings can be patterns (they are always true but they work).

`~` is a regular expression match operator in awk. You can use that to manually perform the same sort of match that the regexp constant pattern does. `~` takes two string arguments.

Putting that together we can match (`~`) the whole line (`$0`) against a string constant regular expression (rather than a regexp constant) of `":"sp" *"` (the string `":"`, our variable `sp`, and the string `" *"`).

Which, when put together, gets you (as I wrote above) `$0 ~ ":"sp" *"` as the pattern instead of the regexp constant.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean under "match a string: `$0 ~ ":"sp" *"`". Could you please explain it for me?

Comment: @АртёмDoe Edited. Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: @АртёмDoe Read http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Regexp and pay particular attention to the difference between `string constants` and `regexp constants` and the section on `Using Dynamic Regexps`. Also, read the book "Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition", by Arnold Robbins if you plan to do more awk programming.